# "X should never stop" vs. "X should never be stopped"

Tags: meaning, verbs, comparison

During the lock down period when students couldn't go to school, I watched a number of clips all recorded by EFL English teachers encouraging students to take part in online classes. The content of the messages they tried to share with their viewers was the same, but they used different wording. The following ones specifically attracted my attention:

> Language learning is a process that should never stop.

> Language learning is a process that should never be stopped.

Are both theses sentences grammatically correct? Do they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

They don't mean quite the same thing. Something can *stop* of its own accord, but if it *is stopped*, someone or something makes it stop.

Presumably the teacher who gave the second message meant that we should not allow current circumstances to stop the process of language learning.